# Select an element, AND if it has an adjacent sibling, select that as well

Tags: javascript, jquery

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RC79G/1/

Dealing with a weird question. This may not be the best way to handle it, but this is the only way I know to do it.

I'm working with Bandsintown which can be a royal pain to customize. It's shooting out a ton of elements. I want to wrap all the Element A's in an `<li>`, but if Element B is below an Element A, I want to wrap them both together.

**Before:**

Element A

Element A

Element A

Element A

Element B

Element A

Element A

**After:**

— Element A —

— Element A —

— Element A —

- Element A Element B —

— Element A —

— Element A —

So I understand how to select the adjacent sibling, but I'm not sure how to select that AND the original element.

Thoughts?

Current code look like this, but you can find a

```
$("div:not('.bit-event-description') + .bit-event-description").wrap("<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4'></div>");
```

Comment: You really should set up a fiddle for this, but the way to do it is to cache the selector and add() the prev() element.

Comment: It looks like you are watching for invalid HTML markup anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you add the previous element when using the next sibling selector

```
var el = $("tr:not('.bit-event-description') + .bit-event-description");
el.add(el.prev()).wrap("<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4'></div>");
```

It's not really clear how that would wrap both Element A and B as there's no markup or any possibilty to test this ?

Comment: "I want to wrap them both together" Shouldn't it be `.wrapAll()` instead?

Comment: @A.Wolff - I was actually about to use wrapAll, but wasn't sure as it was hard to see how this would work, so I wrote the last line in the answer instead, but good eye !